# Is it possible to set a custom background image to grouped tableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to set a custom background (image) to my grouped table view.
In xib file I added the imageView under the table, set table's back to clearColor and it looks normal (in Xib!) But when I launch the application I see standard background

In Xib file:

[image]

In Application:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// instead of adding a UIImageView to the background
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name"]];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: yeah, thanks, it works. Strange that my code doesn't work for grouped table.